# problems installing Zend Framework 2 in 1 and 1 shared hosting

Tags: deployment, zend-framework2

I'm trying to deploy on a 1&1 shared linux hosting the Zend Skeleton Application that I obtained from github (https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) via a SSH connection.

I have those files already in the server, but when doing the installation's last step that's explained in github (php composer.phar install) I get the following error:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.4.9
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in <b>/homepages/45/d*******/htdocs/zend_test/ZendSkeletonApplication/composer.phar</b> on line <b>75</b><br />
```

I can see that the PHP version that shows there is 4.4.9, but I've set up the server to have php 5 (**phpinfo()** shows 5.4.7). I've also included an .htaccess file in the root of the installation's folder with the **AddType x-mapp-php5 .php** instruction, as explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFUSER/Zend+Framework+Web+Hosts), but that doesn't seem to do anything.

**EDIT:**
Files structure as requested below:

```
[root]
    [vendor]
      [ZF2]
         [bin]
         [demos]
         [library]
         [resources]
         [vendor]
         composer.json
         LICENSE.txt
         README.md
      .gitignore
      README.md`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of following the directions in github I downloaded the skeleton app from there and manually added the ZF2 library in the **vendors** folder and all worked fine

Comment: To Albert, could you please show me the structure you have under vendors? For me the library is under vendors/zendframework/zendframework/library/... Also did you manage to get ZF2 running without executing composer.phar install? Thanks

Comment: @Bobby I edit my question to show the structure. Let me know if that's not what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

Try `/usr/local/bin/php5 composer.phar install`

Otherwise 1&1 would be the best people to contact for gaining access to PHP5 on the command line.

Comment: thank you, I found another way to do it. Basically, downloading the whole thing separately instead of going through the automatic install instructions using git and composer

Comment: This doesn't work, at least not with the currently stable version of composer, because the executable at `/usr/local/bin/php5` is too old. You can use `/usr/bin/php6` now, though.

Answer (score 0):

The default PHP executable is PHP4 (4.4.9) for whatever reasons. You have to manually select the right PHP executable to get Composer running. There's a `php5` executable at `/usr/bin/php5` but it is 5.2.17 at the day of writing this, which is not sufficient to run composer, minimum is 5.3.2.

They also have a newer PHP 5 executable comically called `php6` located at `/usr/bin/php6` which is currently version 5.4.19. This one will do the job.

To install composer use this:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php6
```

To use composer use this:

```
php6 composer.phar
```